# Observing new questions of combination of union and intersections of tags

Tags: support, tags, notifications, filtering, tag-watching

How can I observe new question of `foo` tag only if they are also tagged with `bar` or `baz`?

---

Real world example: how can I observe [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions which are also tagged with either [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) or [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string)

---

Lets say that there are tags which are similar, but are not synonyms :

- `bar`
- `baz`

I can observe new questions with at leas one of these tags by using `OR` option like

```
[bar] OR [baz]
```

But now I would like to observe new questions from these tags only if they have some additional (mandatory) tag like `foo`.

I tried with

```
[foo][bar] OR [foo][baz]
([foo][bar]) OR ([foo][baz])
[foo]([bar] or [baz])
```

even

```
[foo][[bar] or [baz]]
```

but they are translated to

```
[bar] or [baz] [foo] [foo]
[bar] or [baz] [foo] [foo]
[bar] or [baz] [foo]
[bar] or [baz] [foo]
```

so `foo` intersects `baz` but not `bar`.

Is there a way to combine union with intersections as described above?

Comment: (foo AND bar) OR (foo AND baz) appears to work.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=(java%20AND%20regex)%20OR%20(java%20AND%20string)%20is%3aquestion) seems to work if I would like to *search* for questions with described tag combination, but this doesn't let me *observe* new ones (unless I misunderstood you).

Comment: @HansPassant Actually after few tests I can see that this search is not based on tags but on content. If I would try to use tags and write it like `([java] AND [regex]) OR ([java] AND [string])` I can't get any results. Also this search query doesn't find newest questions, for instance [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25038301/1393766) is tagged with `[java][regex]` but was not included in result (I blame caching). Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: @Pshemo the question that you linked in above comment is not there anymore..

Comment: @HarshBaid It was removed by its author, probably because it got few downvotes. Point is that it existed for over 20 minutes and was not found by search engine (using query I mentioned earlier) so this way I am not able to observe very new questions (I assume that results available for search engine are updated/cached once every hour or half an hour).

Answer (score 3):

Although the search box doesn't seem to support `[string] [java] OR [regex] [java]` (transforming it to `[java] or [regex] [string] [java]`), you can move the `or` in the resulting URL to get the desired result:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string+java+or+regex+java

Comment: I tested it on `swing` and `android` tags (the are most popular in `java` tag) with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+java+or+swing+java on Chrome, Opera and Firefox but I didn't get any notifications about new questions. I am wondering if it is bug or desired behaviour since here all new questions appear if I refresh the page (there is no caching problem like in case of [*search*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=(java%20AND%20regex)%20OR%20(java%20AND%20string)%20is%3aquestion)).

Comment: Here is question about lack of this notifications: [Lack of notifications about new questions when union and intersection of tags is used](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267336/1393766) (I know you know about it, but some readers may also be interested in it).