# Lack of notifications about new questions when union and intersection of tags is used

Tags: bug, feature-request, tags, notifications

<sub>I am not sure if I should tag this question with [bug] or [feature-request] since don't know if this conditional lack functionality is a desired behaviour or not. Anyway I would love to have this functionality by either solving bug or by removing current limits. If someone has knowledge about problem described below feel free to re-tag my question accordingly.</sub>

---

Recently I asked [how can I observe new questions from combination of tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267205/how-can-i-combine-union-and-intersections-of-tags) in form like

```
([foo] AND [bar]) OR ([foo] and [baz])
```

(for example: I want to observe only [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions which are mandatory tagged also with either [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) or [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex))

and I believe I got [answer which should work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267328/1393766): in short use URL in form:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo+bar+or+foo+baz
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but unfortunately there is problem with it - I don't see notification of new questions

[image]

Everything works fine if I use only `and` or `or` operators like

```
[tag1][tag2][tag3]
[tag1] or [tag2] or [tag3]
```

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+android+or+regex

but it seems that this problem appears only if I combine them

```
[foo] or [bar][baz]
[foo][bar] or [foo][baz]
```

Example (here notifications **are not shown**):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+or+java+swing

---

Is this a bug or desired behaviour?

BTW: I tested it on Chrome, Opera and Firefox (all updated).

Comment: I instinctively tried to click on `&nbsp;7 questions with new activity&nbsp;`.

Comment: Just mash the refresh button :-) If enough people do that and the server load gets high enough, SE will surely implement it.