# Is it possible to subscribe to an intersection of tags?

Tags: support, feature-request

Consider two popular tags, tag1 and tag2. I can't subscribe to any of them as-is, since I would just drown. However, their intersection is something I can manage flow-wise, and is what's more interesting for me to read and perhaps answer.

Can I subscribe to just the intersection?

Note: The [supposed-dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370430/let-me-save-the-intersection-of-2-tags-as-a-favorite?noredirect=1&lq=1) is about marking favorites, this question is about subscription. Related, but not the same feature.

Comment: Related: [Observing new questions of combination of union and intersections of tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267205/215552)

Comment: @MichaelGaskill: The other question is about marking as favorite, this is about subscription.