# Let me save the intersection of 2+ tags as a favorite

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

Suppose I'm a C# developer, but I only program in Windows Forms. I might add [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) as a favorite tag, but then I get C# web questions too. I might put in [windows-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms) as a favorite, but then I get VB.NET questions. I only want C# Windows Forms questions.

It's not that there's no way to do this currently, but can it really be said to be as convenient as saving *one* tag as a favorite?

Given that people are discussing nuking the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag and turning it into [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) as though those are equivalent, it seems like this is a feature whose time has come:

**We need a way to save the intersection of two or more tags as a favorite** as easily as we can currently save a single tag as a favorite.

Comment: This would be a divorce of the fundamental principle that tags are flat and context independent (a tag should work "as the only tag on a question").

Comment: @Braiam So you're saying they should keep the excel-vba tag, then?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand what you ask. This search result does what you want [`winforms + c#`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms+c%23) but instead of a search you want it set as favorite so your front-page is better tailored, right?

Comment: @rene Yes.  Along other things, this change would probably make the Interesting tab more genuinely interesting.

Comment: @Braiam I see nothing here that bars a tag from being the only tag on a question. In fact, this is purely for the person _searching_ for questions- They want questions specifically tagged. It'd be like bookmarking the search for those two tags. In fact, this embraces the purpose of tags: To make finding questions easier.

Comment: @Kendra You can already do that, with the search. This is status-complete, no?

Comment: @Braiam You can achieve a similar effect, sure. But this feature-request is asking for a _built-in_ save button for that search, which would be like what the new-nav had before it was pulled from testing. This isn't status-complete in how it's being presented, it's status-work-around-available.

Comment: @Kendra which again goes against the principle that tags are flat, or in another terms, horizontal. There's no relationships between one and the other. The new-new-nav enabled people to save custom *searches*, which is what SE solution would ultimately looks like, because is cheaper compared to reworking how favorites work.

Comment: @RyanLundy If [excel-vba] is more efficient at getting answerers the questions that they want to answer, hell yeah, keep it. There are other tags that doesn't offer the same performance gains that [excel-vba] is offering compared to their "generic" counterparts.

Comment: And again, @Braiam, this request has _nothing_ to do with tags being flat, and isn't asking to permanently tie tags together everywhere based on what one person wants to is. It's, at its core, going to be exactly what new-nav did: A saved custom search based on two tags. That's what I tried to explain in my first comment, apologies if I was a bit unclear.

Comment: IIRC this is a feature that is already planned under the new-new-nav

Comment: This feature existed; some of us really really liked it. And there was a promise that it would be returned to us. ... [Plaintive comment from six months ago, for reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0#comment538872_359643)

Comment: Very good feature request. Similarly, it would be great to have a tag plus a blocked tag as a favourite.

Comment: This used to be possible with the [new navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate), as you could configure your own tabs and add search criteria to them. However, it was put put [on hold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0) in preparation of channels and navigation 3.0 (aka the new-new nav). However, as far as I'm aware there's no ETA, so let's guesstimate that it will ship in 6 - 8 weeks/months/years.

Comment: @Braiam Except that [tag:excel-vba] seems to be less efficient at getting answers than [`excel`+`vba`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/869314/discoverability-metrics-per-tag-average-time-to-first-answer).

Comment: Suggest it as a new feature of the left nav. (saved searches)

Comment: the "one tag per question works" condition may be true, but there are just so many useful combinations we frequently have to use, the one mentioned in OP is one of that kind: a framework (windows-forms) and multiple languages that target it, where *some might* want to rather not focus on vb.net - excellent feature request, will save time and increase productivity.

Comment: Another way to approach this might be to simply rate all combinations of 2+ interesting tags much higher than a single interesting tag. Then we wouldn't even need to explicitly save the intersection. I imagine it would give everyone much better results: if I'm into NodeJS, and I'm into the Google Places API, I'm going to be super into a question that accesses that API with NodeJS.

Comment: @SteveBennett Except that there are situations where I am interested only in the intersection, and I am not at all interested in the individual tags on their own. In the OP's case, he doesn't want to see the WinForms questions written in languages other than C#, nor does he want to see C# questions unrelated to WinForms.

Comment: Yeah, acknowledged.

Answer (score 28):

You need to invent a time machine, or [wait 6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/215067).

The reason for the time machine is that that feature was natively supported in the past using the [new navigation feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate).

You have to wait because they "promised" support for this in their new navigation, [half a year ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0).

The only way they officially support it now, is as [@Ansgar Wiechers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370456) says, using bookmarks.

Comment: I wouldn't call using bookmarks "official."

Comment: @RyanLundy Well, they do officially support bookmarkable URLs, which could be considered similar...

Comment: The time machine could also be for going into the future ;)

Comment: I still don't understand why you'd want to invert a time machine...

Comment: @MatthieuM.So you could travel through time while upside down?

Comment: This appears to be in progress according to the [latest monthly product team update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312041/299995)

Comment: @MatthieuM. It helps when following non-orientable timelike paths.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You need to invert a time machine because using a time machine you can only go forwards in time ;)

Comment: I was wondering where this feature had gone. It was incredibly useful.

Comment: Has it been six to eight weeks yet?

Comment: @RyanLundy Sign up for the 'Custom Question Lists' beta, it contains a similar feature that you can quickly access that has multiple tags in it

Comment: Thanks, @Ferrybig, I've done that.  For anyone else who doesn't know where to find it: Go to your profile > Edit profile and settings tab > Preferences (sidebar) > Custom Question Lists, check "Opt me in".

Answer (score -10):

If all you want is save a tag search you could just bookmark the search result in your browser, e.g.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel+vba
```

Comment: True...but I'm looking for feature parity between single tags and tag intersections.  For example, I can add single tags to my favorites on the right, but I can't do that with tag intersections.

Comment: And clutter your browser with bookmarks? No, thanks. The "new nav" allowed this **on-site** before it was wrongly left behind

Comment: I don't know why this answer has too many downvotes? Sure, it would be better if SO implemented this feature themselves, but Ansgar is just providing an immediate, if imperfect solution, which is definitely more practical than a time machine.

Comment: @jambrothers downvotes on meta are only to show disagreement/unhelpfulness etc., they don't have any effect on reputation and are only meant to show what the public opinion of the answer is. In this case it could be that while people may appreciate the work around, they'd rather have the functionality requested in the question.

Comment: @jambrothers I would view the ratio of up-/downvotes as a gauge of how willing SO members are to accept a workaround over an "in-app" solution rather than a rating of the actual workaround.

Comment: @NickA, OK thanks, now I know why there are loads of downvotes :)

Comment: It's like answering "You want a bike but can't buy one ? Well, if all you want is reach point B from point A faster, you can run.". I'am sorry to say that, but it's how dumb this is. Now don't get me wrong it surely is a great work around but regarding OP's question it's clearly not helpfull. At least it's how i see it.

Comment: @xoxel You know, I can understand people downvoting the suggested workaround because they want a solution inside SO. But I most certainly resent being called dumb for proposing a functional workaround to something that currently is not possible otherwise.